# error:package android support.test does not exist

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to build an app in android studio and I am encountering an error which has only started to come up recently. As far as I am aware I have not changed any settings or amended any system files which would cause the error to happen. I have tried reinstalling android studio but the error is still happening so I am starting to think it is a coding issue. The error is below:

```
Gradle task[clean, :app:generateDebugSources,:app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :appcompileDebugSources, :app:complieDebugSources, :app: compileDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:compileDebugUnitTestSources]
  C:\Users\Stuart\Documents\TourApp\App\src\androidTest\java\com\example\android\tourapp\ExampleInstrumentedTest.java
error: package android.support.test does not exist
error: package android.support.test.runner does not exist
error: package android org.junit does not exist
error: package android org.junit.runner does not exist
error: package android org.junit does not exist
error: cannot find symbol class RunWith
error: cannot find symbol class Test
error: cannot find symbol variable InstrumentationRegistry
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugAndroidTestJavaWithJavac'.
Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Any ideas what could be causing this?

[image: Android Studio Error]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JUnit tests in Android from Gradle: "package android.test does not exist"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21866449/junit-tests-in-android-from-gradle-package-android-test-does-not-exist)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try adding following lines under dependencies section in `app/build.gradle` file

```
dependencies {

     testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
     //androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Also, you can use **`androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'`** as an alternate.

Comment: `testCompile` is now deprecated, use `testImplementation` instead

Comment: already used but still problem

Answer (score 1):

this happen to me android preview hedgehod 2023
there something error in xml but you cannot find,
go to code -> inspect code -> whole project,
some error (!) will show and after fix, try to build again your project