# After Android Studio and Gradle plugin update error: package android.support.test does not exist

Tags: java, android, gradle, package

I've updated the Android Studio to 2023.1.1 and the Gradle plugin to 8.2.0.
This Android app has not been touched for ~ 1.5 years, and I've decided to compile it and change the target SDK (now 33, previously 29).

Before the code was compiling without any warning message.
Now, when I try to compile, I get a lot of `package not exist` errors, like below:

```
D:\work_area\android_projects\BubblesInLine\app\src\androidTest\java\ro\notnull\bubblesinline\ExampleInstrumentedTest.java:4: error: package android.support.test does not exist
import android.support.test.InstrumentationRegistry;
                           ^
D:\work_area\android_projects\BubblesInLine\app\src\androidTest\java\ro\notnull\bubblesinline\ExampleInstrumentedTest.java:5: error: package android.support.test.runner does not exist
import android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4;
                                  ^
D:\work_area\android_projects\BubblesInLine\app\src\androidTest\java\ro\notnull\bubblesinline\ExampleInstrumentedTest.java:7: error: package org.junit does not exist
import org.junit.Test;
                ^
D:\work_area\android_projects\BubblesInLine\app\src\androidTest\java\ro\notnull\bubblesinline\ExampleInstrumentedTest.java:8: error: package org.junit.runner does not exist
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
                       ^
D:\work_area\android_projects\BubblesInLine\app\src\androidTest\java\ro\notnull\bubblesinline\ExampleInstrumentedTest.java:10: error: package org.junit does not exist
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
                       ^
D:\work_area\android_projects\BubblesInLine\app\src\androidTest\java\ro\notnull\bubblesinline\ExampleInstrumentedTest.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
 ^
  symbol: class RunWith
D:\work_area\android_projects\BubblesInLine\app\src\androidTest\java\ro\notnull\bubblesinline\ExampleInstrumentedTest.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
         ^
  symbol: class AndroidJUnit4
D:\work_area\android_projects\BubblesInLine\app\src\androidTest\java\ro\notnull\bubblesinline\ExampleInstrumentedTest.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
    @Test
     ^
  symbol:   class Test
  location: class ExampleInstrumentedTest
D:\work_area\android_projects\BubblesInLine\app\src\androidTest\java\ro\notnull\bubblesinline\ExampleInstrumentedTest.java:22: error: cannot find symbol
        Context appContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext();
                             ^
  symbol:   variable InstrumentationRegistry
  location: class ExampleInstrumentedTest
D:\work_area\android_projects\BubblesInLine\app\src\androidTest\java\ro\notnull\bubblesinline\ExampleInstrumentedTest.java:24: error: cannot find symbol
        assertEquals("ro.notnull.bubblesinline", appContext.getPackageName());
        ^
  symbol:   method assertEquals(String,String)
  location: class ExampleInstrumentedTest
```

My build.gradle file looks like below

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias '********'
            keyPassword '********'
            storeFile file('D:/work_area/android/apps/keys_store/free_apps/android_free_apps.jks')
            storePassword '********'
        }
    }



    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ro.notnull.bubblesinline"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 33
        compileSdk 33
        versionCode 11
        versionName "1.7.2"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            debuggable false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
            shrinkResources true
        }
        debug {
            //buildConfigField("String", "BUILD_TIME", "\"0\"")
            debuggable true
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    namespace 'ro.notnull.bubblesinline'

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation "androidx.gridlayout:gridlayout:1.0.0"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:22.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.3.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

}
```

As specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073763/errorpackage-android-support-test-does-not-exist), I've added `testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'`, but it didn't help.
Before I had in the build.gradle file `//testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'`, the line was actually commented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved in the end.

The problems

- android.support.test.InstrumentationRegistry was replaced by androidx.test.platform.app.InstrumentationRegistry , see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/InstrumentationRegistry
- android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4 was replaced by androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4 , see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/runner/AndroidJUnit4

So, I've added next lines on the build.gradle file

```
dependencies {
    // other/old lines ...
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.5.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
}
```

And proper import statements in ExampleInstrumentedTest.java file

```
import androidx.test.platform.app.InstrumentationRegistry;
import androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4;
```